Could the gamma ray burst on 12/27/2004 caused the Tsunami on 12/26/2004? Is there a pressure wave in front of the blast?
Tsunami on 12/26/2004
Gamma ray blast on 12/27/2004 that ionized the stratosphere

For one thing, nothing travels faster than light, so anything that preceded the gamma rays' arrival could not have been associated with it and arrived first

So you are saying that there is no gravitational wave or energy wave that could possibly be being produced by the gamma ray?

There are all kinds of energy forms that we don’t understand or even perceive. I’m just saying that the odds of these two events happening within 24 hours of each other should bring us to wonder if we should be investigating this

@seanduren GRBs actually do occur in concert with gravitational waves sometimes, because events that create GRBs usually involve supermassive astrophysical objects doing something violent. But the most intense gravitational waves ever observed by humanity take ultra-high-precision instruments like LIGO to accurately detect, and change the length of a kilometer-long interferometer leg by less than the width of a proton. A gravwave hitting the Earth would be roughly equivalent to dropping a grain of sand in the ocean; not nearly enough to cause a tsunami.

No, there is no gravitational wave or any form of cause and effect we have ever observed that travels faster than light. While these two events may seem to coincide meaningfully, you could point to any number of events that happened on 12/26/04 (a solar flare, a military explosion in Afghanistan, a child blowing out a birthday candle at that moment) and draw a similar proposed link between them and the tsunami.  Without some definite physical mechanism for the causal link, these pairings are not meaningful

No. Gamma-ray bursts are interesting astrophysical events, not events that physically interact with most of the Earth. If it was powerful enough to cause a tsunami due to radiation pressure, it would also be powerful enough to measurably change the Earth's orbit as well as sterilize the entire planet. The fact that we still exists proves that these two events are not correlated.
Also note that, unless you have your dates switched around, the tsunami happened before the gamma ray burst was detected. Since nothing can travel faster than light in flat spacetime, there is no physical way for the GRB to have affected Earth at all at the time of the tsunami.

It did affect our atmosphere and the gravitational field surrounding earth!

@seanduren It did not affect the atmosphere nearly enough to cause a tsunami. If a GRB were close enough to cause substantial effects to the gravitational field of the planet, then it would also sterilize the planet; gravitational fields are exceptionally difficult to modify with radiation alone. It may have affected the magnetic field, which is more responsive to radiated particles like alpha, beta, gamma radiation that the GRB may have emitted. But it did not substantially affect the atmosphere... (1/2)

(2/2) It may have ionized the upper atmosphere, but that does not constitute a change to the "atmosphere" as would cause meteorological effects beyond aurorae in the upper latitudes. For context, the Sun also frequently ionizes the upper atmosphere, and there are no data to suggest that such events correlate to tsunamis or any other natural disaster, barring EMR interference with geosynchronous satellites  (completely unrelated to the atmosphere anyway)
